# How do I assign a different delivery driver to each order that has been created?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

so I have a sql table with columns such as driverid and drivername

The code below creates the order once the customer checks out.

```cs
string deliveryDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("M/d/yyyy");
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);

if (Session["buyitems"] != null && Session["Orderid"] != null)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["buyitems"];
    for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        string pId = dt.Rows[i]["pid"].ToString();
        int pQuantity = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i]["pquantity"]);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Pquantity from ProductShirt where ProductId ='" + pId + "' ", con);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtbl);

        int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dtbl.Rows[0][0]);
        if (quantity > 0)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into OrderDetails(orderid,sno,productid,productname,price,quantity,orderdate,status,email,deliverydate,address, driverid) values('" + Session["Orderid"] + "',"
                                 + dt.Rows[i]["sno"] + "," + dt.Rows[i]["pid"] + ",'" + dt.Rows[i]["pname"] + "'," + (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["pprice"])) + "," + dt.Rows[i]["pquantity"] + ",'" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "','Pending', '" + Session["username"].ToString() + "', '" + deliveryDate + "', '" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + driverid + '")", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    decreaseQuantity();
    clearCart();
    Session["buyitems"] = null;
    Session["deliverydate"] = deliveryDate;
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("AddtoCart.aspx");
}
```

How would I go about assigning a different delivery driver to a new order, for example when the first order has been created, driver1 is assigned to it. When the third order has been created, driver3 is assigned to it but say if there's a fourth order, the list of drivers being assigned should start with driver 1 all over again.

Comment: Use a queue. The most simple implementation is an in-memory object that knows the list of the drivers and remembers the last one. This object centralizes the logic of the assignment of drivers (that could change in the future). If you have a multithreaded app, then the critical section should be synchronized.

Comment: Since you're using a database, one approach might be to create a table that has one column and one row that contains the last assigned driver. The value is read before an order is assigned, and updated once the order has been assigned. If this is a class assignment your approach to the issue is probably fine. However, if this is an application for the real-world, assigning one driver to one order seems inefficient. It may be more efficient to assign multiple orders to a driver - as long as the multiple orders are along the route.

Comment: Seems to me you can just put a list of drivers at the top of your function and use the index of the orders using modulus on driver count to determine driver index `drivers[i % drivers.Count()]` (assuming the list of drivers variable is called drivers)

Comment: *list of drivers being assigned should start with driver 1 all over again* - why? This logic of assigning drivers in round robin order seems rather unstructured. Orders should perhaps be assigned to areas/drivers should cover orders in a certain area

Comment: and most important - use sql parameters ...